# Proving equality of $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ and $\lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h)$; is my proof valid?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, epsilon-delta

My question is about my proof: whether a specific step I'm making is valid. My proof is as follows:

Suppose that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists, and that it is equal to $L$. Then, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - a| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

So write $h = x - a$, and fix $\epsilon' > 0$. Then, there exists a $\delta' > 0$ such that $|x - a| = |h| < \delta'$ implies $|f(x) - L| = |f(a + h) - L| < \epsilon'$, so $\lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h) = L$.

My proof for the other direction is very similar, so I won't post it, but my question is about the step "So write $h = x - a$". Is this a valid step? The reason I'm asking is that I'm not sure that I can just define $h$ however I like.

Comment: Yes, it is. In fact it is rather useful substitution sometimes to evaluate all kinds of limits.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: You just have to be careful you put in in context.  Set $\epsilon$ first.  THe conclude there is a $\delta$ where $|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) -L|< \epsilon$.  Then we set an $h$ so that $|h-0| < \delta$.  *NOW* we define $x=h+a$ (rather than the other way around) and show that $|x-a|=|h+a -a|=|h| < \delta$ and so $|f(x)- L|<\epsilon$ but $|f(x)-L|=|f(a+h) -L|$ and so $|h-0|<\delta\implies |f(a+h)-L|< \epsilon$ so we are done.